# JSON Response Parsing in WP7

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7

I have a JSON Response from web api as this

```
{"payload":{"items":{"11204":{"title":"The Ugliest Girl?","item_id":"11204","thumb_url":"http:google.11204.jpg","teaser":"We live in the internet generationher purpose in life to her through this adversity.","language_id":"en","media_id":1,"views":"5","shares":"0"},"11228":{"title":"Depressed","item_id":"11228","thumb_url":"http:google.11228.jpg","teaser":"We all get discouraged at times, especially when things go wrong or other people hurt us. Sometimes we can seem to go through a string of disappointments that compound our sadness till we wonder.","language_id":"en","media_id":5,"views":"35","shares":"2"}}
```

and many more objects in similar manner

How can i parse this to Dictionary or in any other way? The response varies depending on the request.

Answer (score 0):

u can parse your json into an object like :

```
var parsed = JObject.Parse(Json);
```

and to get a specific value :

```
var value = parsed[key];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a service like [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) you can convert your json to C#. Given the json that you have, you will need to modify the classes slightly. Here are consumable classes

```
public class Item
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string item_id { get; set; }
    public string thumb_url { get; set; }
    public string teaser { get; set; }
    public string language_id { get; set; }
    public int media_id { get; set; }
    public string views { get; set; }
    public string shares { get; set; }
}

public class Payload
{
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

From there you can use a library like Json.Net to convert from the json to these objects. Normally you would be able to convert directly to your classes, but because of the indexes in the names, this is not possible.  So you will have to do some conversion yourself.

```
public Payload ConvertJson(string json)
{
    var payload = new Payload();

    var container = JToken.Parse(json) as JContainer;
    if(container == null) return payload;

    payload.Items = new List<Item>(container.Count);

    foreach (var child in container)
    {
        var childJson = child.FirstOrDefault();
        if (childJson == null) continue;

        var item = childJson.ToObject<Item>();
        if (item.item_id == 0)
        {
            item.item_id = Convert.ToInt32(((JProperty)child).Name);
        }
        payload.Items.Add(item);
    }
    return payload;
}
```